# Any fast way to get “average” color of OpenGL texture or render buffer?

Tags: opengl

I have an OpenGl application on an operating system that can snatch the OpenGL context away when the application loses focus, even though the application remains in memory. This results in a screen flicker as I re-load textures into the new OpenGL context when the application returns to focus.

I am working on breaking up the re-loading into increments so it looks better. But I am also wondering about this possibility:

1. When the program gets notice that it will lose focus, capture the  “average” color of the display (or the primary texture).
2. When the program regains focus, do a very quick glClearColor(r,g,b) with the color captured in step 1.
3. Then, re-load the textures normally while the user sees the color set in step 2.

I am thinking this would be sort of a visual trick to make the flicker less noticeable. There’s a catch: I am thinking that capturing an aggregate color by averaging every pixel would take too long and not be worth it.

So I am wondering if there is any OpenGl trick that would let an application get a rough estimate of the average color that a user sees on the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest way I've heard of to average a screen's color is to copy it to a texture, call [`glGenerateMipmap`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGenerateMipmap), and grab the smallest layer (1x1 mip level), which will contain an average of the colors of the pixel. That doesn't sound particularly fast to me though, so not sure if it will be helpful for your purposes.

Comment: mipmap generation is probably going to be quicker than anything else you can do. I'd test that against a few other solutions before I take that as fact, though.

Comment: Note that some OpenGL implementations (e.g. Mesa, see [this bug report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/1037)) generate badly aliased mipmap if the level-0 texture has non-power-of-two size. In this case the deepest mip level will be far from the average color of the level 0. For such cases you might want to pad the data with texels to fill a power-of-two texture (round-up of actual data dimensions), and then scale the value of the deepest mip level as `avg = deepestMipTexel*(roundedWidth*roundedHeight)/(dataWidth*dataHeight)`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a Histogram.  GPU gems has an article that includes a description of using the geometry shader to make one.

https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch41.html

Nicol's method or variants of would probably be quicker though (and certainly a lot less code) but not so easy to tweak.

Comment: The link is broken. Here is the working link: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch41.html